# Button element does not respect text-overflow: ellipsis container

Tags: html, css

I have an app with both `<a>` and `<button>` elements that are styled to look alike. For the most part, the two behave identically. However, in a `text-overflow: ellipsis` container, the button text is clipped without receiving ellipses. Example: http://codepen.io/TrevorBurnham/pen/pNxeVW

```css
.text-overflow-ellipsis {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 250px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.link-button {
  display: inline;
  font: inherit;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
}
a, button {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="text-overflow-ellipsis">
  <a>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</a>      
</div>
<div class="text-overflow-ellipsis">
  <button class="link-button">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</button>      
</div>
```

[image: ellipsis-link-and-button]

In this case, the `<button>` is an inline element. In fact, as far as I can tell, it has all of the same (relevant) CSS properties as the `<a>` element! Yet it behaves differently in this one context. At first I thought this had to be a browser bug, but I'm seeing the same behavior in Chrome, Safari, Firefox, and Edge.

What's so special about `<button>` here? Is this behavior determined by [the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-ui-3/#text-overflow)? And is there any way to make `<button>` behave like `<a>` does here?

(I know that I could make the `<button>` itself a `text-overflow: ellipsis` container to create the *effect* I want, but I want to understanding what's going on. I'm only interested in either a pure CSS solution, or an explanation for why no such solution is possible.)

Comment: Please include your full code, this would surely help the rest of us to answer your question, not having the full code can lead to the question being flagged, and closed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because buttons are replaced elements. They can't be displayed inline, your `display: inline` in fact behaves like `display: inline-block`. This is indeed determined by the [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#inline-boxes):

> A non-replaced element with a 'display' value of 'inline' generates an
>   inline box. Inline-level boxes that are not inline boxes (such as
>   replaced inline-level elements, inline-block elements, and
>   inline-table elements) are called atomic inline-level boxes because
>   they participate in their inline formatting context as a single opaque
>   box.

So you need to set `text-overflow` directly to the button, which is the block container.

```css
.text-overflow-ellipsis {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 250px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.link-button {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  display: inline;
  font: inherit;
  background: none;
}
a, button {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="text-overflow-ellipsis">
  <a>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</a>      
</div>
<div>
  <button class="link-button text-overflow-ellipsis">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</button>      
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, just the kind of answer I was looking for!